# java.io.IOException source exists but not in a directory

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a real beginner at Java programming so I hope I'm not wasting anyone's time. I tried my best to research this but couldn't come up with a solution.

I am following the Lynda video series "Java Essential Training" and it's been very good so far. I am currently learning how to copy the contents of a text file onto a new text file. However, the video shows a alternative method by downloading commons IO from Apache commons and adding the .jar file to the project.

In the video the jar file was added to build path. My version of eclipse seemed to do it automatically as "Referenced Libraries" popped up, and when I tried to add it eclipse said it was already there.

I followed the video exactly. The code looks like this

```
package com.lynda.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         File f1 = new File("loremipsum.txt");
         File f2 = new File("target.txt");

         FileUtils.copyDirectory(f1, f2);

         System.out.println("File copied!");
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

When I ran the code I got the message in console

```
java.io.IOException: Source 'loremipsum.txt' exists but is not a directory
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1371)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1261)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1230)
at com.lynda.files.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

In the code it says the FileUtils imported but eclipse tells me "The source attachment does not contain the source for file FileUtils.class". I tried to change the attached source but it gave me the error "Could not write to file BlahBlahBlah.classpath (Access is denied)

Hopefully I didn't drone on about something obvious and simple. I thought it best to be as clear as possible in case someone else has a similar problem.

Edit

I feel so stupid. Thank you for your help. I clicked on "copyDirectory" instead of "copyFile". Next time, instead of panicking, googling every line of error and asking people for help, I'll take the time to go through each line and think about what it does. Thanks to all of you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2):

See (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Use `FileUtils.copyFile(f1, f2);` instead of `FileUtils.copyDirectory(f1, f2);`

Answer (score 1):

I found this that may be of help to you:

- copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) Copies a file to a new location preserving the file date.
- static void   copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, boolean preserveFileDate) Copies a file to a new location.
- static long   copyFile(File input, OutputStream output) Copy bytes from a File to an OutputStream.
- static void   copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir) Copies a file to a directory preserving the file date.
- static void   copyFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir, boolean preserveFileDate) Copies a file to a directory optionally preserving the file date.

[Source](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Although it's from the Apache site, it does talk about the Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

The source and target File parameters of `copyDirectory` must be directories, but you are suppling text files.

```
public static void copyDirectory(File srcDir,File destDir)
    throws IOException

Copies a whole directory to a new location preserving the file dates.

This method copies the specified directory and all its child directories and files to the specified destination. The destination is the new location and name of the directory.

The destination directory is created if it does not exist. If the destination directory did exist, then this method merges the source with the destination, with the source taking precedence.

Note: This method tries to preserve the files' last modified date/times using File.setLastModified(long), however it is not guaranteed that those operations will succeed. If the modification operation fails, no indication is provided.

Parameters:
    srcDir - an existing directory to copy, must not be null
    destDir - the new directory, must not be null
Throws:
    NullPointerException - if source or destination is null
    IOException - if source or destination is invalid
    IOException - if an IO error occurs during copying
Since:
    1.1
```

([Source](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29))

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message again:

> Source 'loremipsum.txt' exists but is not a directory

This is not exactly what you wrote in your subject. Indeed the file 'loremipsum.txt' exists but it *not* a directory. It is regular file. However you try to call `FileUtils.copyDirectory()` and pass this regular file to this method. But this method is not ready to work with files. It supports directories only. This is exactly what is written in error message.

EDIT

Now the question is why do you call method that definitely for intended for directories with parameters that are definitely files?